# Auto update facebook user info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that has a facebook login. Its been running for quite a while now and has had quite a few users sign up. In the database I have recorded their names | emails | facebook id # | access token . In hindsight I should have also recorded their age & location.

Is it possible to auto update my database with the needed information without the need for the user to revisit the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. those information require special rights so a new fb access token to update your database.

How to do that: Update your FB application with the rights you want:

[image]

Then force your users to use the facebook login again. With the new access token you will be able to get those data.

**Edit**: if your application already has the correct rights, you just need the access token to get user info.

*test done with the* [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
[image]

The request is **https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?** with as parameter the access token and the properties you need (here the birthday, name and id)

If users' access token are stored in database, a simple script with call to the api and update of the database will do the trick. If no, you will have to force your users to do it again to save your access token and use it to get the info you need.

Comment: Thank you. My app is already approved to get age . Can I obtain at least that without the user revisiting my page?

Comment: I added a comment with more details about how to do that